# Using GCD how can a DispatchGroup have items run on the main queue from a background queue before (or just after) the group leaves, without deadlock?

Tags: swift, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

Given some class `Foo` that calls Bar on a background thread to perform some work, how can `Bar` set some work to be done on the main thread without causing a deadlock, before the enclosing function returns the value it needs to return?

E.g. how can "asdf" print before "done" prints, before `true` is returned from `func done() -> Bool` in the example below?

```swift
import Dispatch

class Foo {
   /// always called from the main queue
   func done() -> Bool {
       let group = DispatchGroup()
       group.enter()
       DispatchQueue.global().async {
           Bar().perform {
               DispatchQueue.main.async { print("asdf") } 
                    // "asdf" prints after "done" is printed
               group.leave()
           }
       }
       group.wait()
       print("done")
       return true
    }
}
```

where `Bar` is simply:

```swift
struct Bar {
    func perform(_ work: @escaping () -> Void) { work() }
}
```

I need Bar to be able to set some work that should be executed on the main queue before `done()` returns, without causing a deadlock (as would happen if we changed the above `perform` block to use `DispatchQueue.main.sync`, and (assuming `done()` is always called on the main thread, which it is).

The only solution I could come up with to print "asdf" before we print "done" is to change the `done()` function as follows:

```swift
    func done() -> Bool {
        let group1 = DispatchGroup()
        var completion: (() -> Void)? = nil
        group1.enter()
        DispatchQueue.global().async(group: group1) {
            Bar().perform {
                completion = { print("asdf") }
                group1.leave()
            }
        }
        group1.wait()
        completion?()
        print("done")
        return true
    }
```

Here the `completion` block runs on the main thread before the function returns. However this feels kludgy and hacky... seems like something that GCD should just handle for us. But everything else I've tried will run after the function returns.

Thoughts?

Comment: Your current code would block the main thread (because of the waiting you do on the `group`) for the entire duration of the background work. There are multiple established solutions for this problem (Completion handlers, futures/promises, Combine, to name a few), but this is really the core problem the new `async`/`await` feature aims to solve.

Comment: What I don't understand is, why can't the main thread do something else while the current task it has was blocked? And why can't we assign something for GCD to run on the main thread just before or just after "wait", similar to what I was able to accomplish above?

Comment: Because GCD threads don't "do something else" while blocked. But `async/await` does _not_ block, so it's exactly what you want. With `async/await` the main thread _can_ go off and do other things while the code pauses.

Comment: "why can't the main thread do something else while the current task it has was blocked?" Because you *explicitly* told the main thread to block by calling `group.wait()`. If you hadn't done that, the main thread would have kicked off the work (which would have worked away on the global queue), and continued on to the rest of its work.

Comment: You are trying to falsify the axiom that says, when calling an async function, the caller becomes async as well. I am pretty sure you cannot do this, even with legal hacks. So, you should start with explaining your problem, not with a question how to make your solution work.

Comment: @matt The problem is, I need to block the function `done() -> Bool` from returning until after some work is done on a background thread and also some other work is done on the main thread. If "group.wait()" tells the main queue to pause execution, I would have thought GCD could also have the ability to tell the main queue to other things as well, like executing tasks after unpausing execution. And indeed it can—via a 1group.notify`—but, apparently not synchronously, as I'd need for that work to get executed before the main queue returns from `done()`. Asked in case I was overlooking anything.

Comment: @Alexander I didn't realize before asking the question that DispatchGroup blocks the whole thread and also doesn't provide any mechanism to schedule some work to happen on that thread before or after a group.wait() statement. I guess what I was looking for is a synchronous "group.notify"... but no dice.

Comment: "a synchronous "group.notify" wouldn't really make sense, it'd be no different then a `wait` and a `sync`.

Answer (score 0):

The main queue under GCD is not re-entrant, and you cannot stop `done` from returning immediately except by blocking the main thread, nor (therefore) can you return a value from `done` after the first async method.

So, as you've been told in a comment, what you're trying to do is impossible.

You can call back into the main thread from *inside* the Bar completion handler, by way (for example) of *another* completion handler; but you cannot "wait" the way you are trying to do.

So for example:

```
struct Bar {
    func perform(_ work: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print("work")
        work()
    }
}
class Foo {
    func done(_ f: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
       DispatchQueue.global().async {
           Bar().perform {
               DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    // adjust the order of these two lines as desired
                    print("asdf")
                    f(true)
               }
           }
       }
    }
}
let f = Foo()
f.done { what in
    print(what)
    print("done")
}
```

Output:

```
work
asdf
true
done
```

Comment: Hmm this one seems to print "asdf" after "done" which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Well, like I said in the comment, just swap those two lines :) Here, I'll swap them for you.

Comment: You changed the function signature of "done()" though. The whole problem is that I'm not at liberty to do that. I should have made that more clear in the original question.

Comment: Well, that doesn't change my answer. You can downvote it because it makes you unhappy, and you can make me delete it, but you cannot change the facts. The main thread is not reentrant under GCD.

Comment: That being said if GCD doesn't support adding code to run on the thread a DispatchGroup was created on before the function it's called on returns, that's surprising because I would have thought `group.notify(...) { print("asdf") }` would have worked but it waits to run the notify closure until after the function exits, even if you specify it to run on the same queue and set its QoS to .userInitiated. Why? Really annoying...

Comment: I'll undownvote this since you addressed the concerns in my comments but I'd like to wait and see if anyone else can provide a way to do this with GCD that one of us might be overlooking. I'm surprised that we'd have to resort to this kind of hacky method with the completion block rather than GCD supporting to inject code to run on the main thread before the current function exits. Why can't it do so without a deadlock I wonder?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've answered that more than once. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that might work for you:

```
struct Bar {
    func perform(work: @escaping () -> Void, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
         onBackGround(work) { 
            DispatchQueue.main.async { 
                print("asdf") 
                completion()
            }
        }
    }

    func done() { 
        print("done")
    }
}
```

Call it:

```
bar = .. 
bar.perform(work) { 
   self.done()
}
```